# Create new operation in Azure APIM api with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management

I already created an API in Azure with folowing code.

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "api-foo" {
  name                = "Example"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "example-foo"
  path                = "apifoo"
  protocols           = ["https", "http"]
  description         = "some text here"
  import {
    content_format = "openapi-link"
    content_value  = "https://publicapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
  }
}
```

Also a root level policy.

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "api-foo" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.api-foo.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  #operation_id        = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.api-foo.operation_id

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
    <inbound>
    <set-backend-service base-url="https://publicapi.azurewebsites.net" />
        <base />     
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
XML
}
```

Now I have more swager definitions with new enpoints and I want to add them in same Api but I don´t know how to achieve this with terraform. Also don´t want to remove the one I already have. If I replace `content_value` with new swager file I will remove the one I already have.
Is there a way to achieve this? Also, how can I get the Operation Id in the output after it gets created? I would want that The ID of new operation get asociated to some policy but not as a root level. Just operation policy level (a new module will have to be created for this new policy)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a different swagger/openapi definition to the same api in an Azure api management instance. By importing an api definition, the api operations are automatically generated by the Azure api management service below the api that you selected as the target.
You can either create a new api in the same Azure api management instance (with a different api suffix than the first one) and import your new definition there, or you can manually combine the api definitions into one file (assuming the apis share the same base api URLs) and replace your existing api with it.
A third but ugly option would be to add the operations from your 2nd api definition manually below the first api in your Azure api management instance, but this will be cumbersome as you also have to manually adjust the policy for each operation to point its backend to the 2nd api definition base URL.

Comment: hmmm, Regarding second approach. They have different base URL. So is:  API-foo. Inside: {operation 1 URL a},  {operations 2 and 3 URL b }.  If I create only one file as you said with all different openapi definitions, couldn´t I just create  individual policies with unique base URL for operations sharing that same base URL? or how can I do that?. Also is just putting one openapi definition just below the next one in one file and thats it?

Comment: Also is it possible to create an operation using operation module from the openapi json?. In most examples I see they use a schema before, but not quite clear how schema is defined for this

Comment: If you plan to use only one API for the two different backend APIs, you have to create different policies for the operations. In the policies, you need to use the `<set-backend-service base-url="base URL of the backend service" />` for pointing to another backend api. You can also point to an Azure API Management backend where you define your URL once and then reference it by using the same policy, like this `<set-backend-service backend-id="identifier of the backend entity specifying base URL of the backend service" />`

Comment: It is currently not possible to create a single operation by using the complete api definition. But you can manually extract the operation definition from your api definition file and use this for the operation schema.

Comment: I read that but wasn´t quite clear on how to extract a operation to import from a schema. I didn´t found a page were they indicate that.  How would be the example for this one? to get the operations in a schema? https://github.com/RaphaelYoshiga/TerraformBasics/blob/master/conference-api.json

Comment: You would need to use the `azurerm_api_management_api_operation` resource at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_operation. For each path of your api definition, you would need to create such a resource.